# cs50 filter-more grayscale expected "20 20 20\n50 5...", not "20 20 20\n50 5..."

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing the cs50 course and I am in week 4 (Memory) and I am doing the homework.

this is my code for [`grayscale`](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/less/):

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            uint8_t Red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            uint8_t Green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            uint8_t Blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            uint8_t avg = (Red + Green + Blue) / 3;

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avg;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = avg;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = avg;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Here are the results
[image]

Can you explain the 27 not 28 and most importantly this: `expected "20 20 20\n50 5...", not "20 20 20\n50 5..."`

Comment: First: probably something to do with integer division and expecting rounding up, not truncation. Second: probably something not in the quoted snippet of output isn't matching.

Comment: Hey, thanks, what do you mean in "Second" ? can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Not really. The expected and actual output probably differ somewhere outside of the quoted bit.

Comment: It doesn't show what's different for the second and third error, so we can't tell what's wrong

Comment: Anyway, you haven't said what the code is supposed to accomplish, so we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: code suppose to make RGB image black and white

Comment: For your temp variables, try changing from `uint8_t` to `int`

Comment: @CraigEstey Not needed, they undergo integer promotion anyway.

Comment: You may have a rounding (round up) issue. Try changing: `avg = (Red + Green + Blue) / 3;` into `avg = (Red + Green + Blue + (3 - 1)) / 3;` That's just a _quick_ guess for the roundup [so it could easily be wrong]. If that doesn't work, you _may_ need to coerce floating point division and use `round`.

Comment: @CraigEstey that's not correct rounding. `(Red + Green + Blue + 1) / 3` should work though.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I did that with insufficient coffee ;-) Thanks.

Comment: You will get more detailed information about the input, expected output and actual output if you follow the link provided by `check50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you for example have the channel values `5`, `4`, and `8`, then the sum of these values is `17` and the average is `5.666667`.

However, in C, when you write `( 5 + 4 + 8 ) / 3`, then this is equivalent to `17 / 3` and will perform an integer division ([euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)), which means the result of the division is `5` with a remainder of `2`. Therefore, the expression `17 / 3` will evaluate to `5` and the expression `17 % 3` will evaluate to `2` (which is the remainder).

An integer division (euclidean division) is not the kind of division that you need for this assignment. Rather, the assignment wants you to perform a division with a fractional part, so the result is `5.666667`, and then this result should be rounded to the nearest integer. Therefore, the result should be `6` in this example.

In C, if both arguments of the `/` operator are of an integer type, then an integer division is performed. If at least one of the arguments is of a floating-point type (such as `float` or `double`), then the other argument is converted to the floating-point type and a floating-point division is performed instead of an integer division, so that the result is a floating-point value with a fractional part.

Therefore, the easiest way to enforce a floating-point division is to change one of the arguments to a floating-point type. This can be done by changing the line

```
uint8_t avg = (Red + Green + Blue) / 3;
```

to:

```
uint8_t avg = (Red + Green + Blue) / 3.0;
```

However, this still won't work, because assigning the value `5.666667` to an integer data type will convert that value to `5`. Instead, the result should be rounded to the nearest integer value, which is `6`. For this, you can use the functions [`round`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/round) or [`lround`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/lround):

```
uint8_t avg = round((Red + Green + Blue) / 3.0);
```

Comment: Since it is `unsigned`, simply adding `0.5` to your result of the division by `3.0` will also work, e.g. `(Red + Green + Blue) / 3.0 + 0.5`.

Comment: Chuckling [CS50 - Pset4 filter](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/more/) has "**Hints** The values of a pixel’s `rgbtRed`, `rgbtGreen`, and `rgbtBlue` components are all integers, so be sure to *round* any floating-point numbers to the nearest integer when assigning them to a pixel value!" (italics added `:)`